# Drupal Twig custom alias for templates in components

Tags: theming, 8

i want to combine a living styleguide generator with drupal 8. The living styleguide generator uses a unique symtax for reusing templates like this "@button"

for the component library itself i use https://www.drupal.org/project/components

The component libary lives in THEME/components
The example layout lives in THEME/components/box/box.twig

I can include this in a Drupal template using it like this:

```
{% include "@components/box/box.twig" with {
  'classes' : classes,
  'attributes' : attributes|without(classes),
  'button' : {
    'modifier' : 'default',
    'label' : 'Read More'
  },
 'paragraph.text' : content.field_body|field_value

}%}
```

The box.twig template itself reuses other components like this:

```
{% include '@button' with { 
  'value' : button.label, 
  'modifier' : button.modifier } 
%}
```

Now Drupal tells me it can't find @button, sure thats true because it does not know the alias structure.

What would be the best way to tell Drupal to look for @components/box/box.twig if it is called with @box ?

Thanks in advance,

yobottehg